# how to get oauth2 authorization code explicitly

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm writing a simple Dropbox app in Python that upload/Download files. Here is the particular piece of code that I am working with that creates a connection to a Dropbox account.

```
flow = dropbox.client.DropboxOAuth2FlowNoRedirect(app_key, app_secret)

# Have the user sign in and authorize this token
authorize_url = flow.start()
print '1. Go to: ' + authorize_url
print '2. Click "Allow" (you might have to log in first)'
print '3. Copy the authorization code.'
code = raw_input("Enter the authorization code here: ").strip()

# This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code
access_token, user_id = flow.finish(code)

client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
print 'linked account: ', client.account_info()

f = open('data.txt')
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', f)
print 'uploaded: ', response

folder_metadata = client.metadata('/')
print 'metadata: ', folder_metadata

f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.txt')
out = open('magnum-opus.txt', 'w')
out.write(f.read())
out.close()
print metadata
```

It seems to work fine, but I am wary of the way I am checking for authentication. The code above will open a link in the user's default browser to his/her Dropbox account to allow access to this app. But i want to skip these steps and get explicit authorized code. i had read [doc](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize) but it does not helps me. Does anyone have any idea how to get this code?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The only way to call the Dropbox API is to have an OAuth token, which requires that the user authorize your app.

Comment: i want to skip the authorization process in browser, just want to get authorization code in script

Comment: That's not possible. A user has to authorize you app before you can access his or her account.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "code" flow. Register a redirect url with dropbox api. Dropbox will send the "code" to the redirect-uri. From the redirect uri, call a REST api in dropbox which will give you the access code. Since, all of this happen on the server side, it is much easier to implement.